# Determine midline equation of the function

Tags: trigonometry

$$ f(x) = -6\sin(3\pi + 4) - 2 $$

Why is $-2$ the midline of the graph of the function?  How to prove that?

Comment: That's a constant function.

Comment: @SalmonKiller is there a way that I can prove that -2 is the midline?

Comment: Are you missing an $x$ in the definition of your function?  If the function is a function of $\sin$(something involving $x$), then the $\sin$ part will vary between $-6$ and $6$, so it varies around the constant part of the function, the $-2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I think there is a typo in the function definition. There is usually an $x$ involved somewhere. However, to answer your question about the midline, the midline is usually the constant after the trig function. It is $-2$ in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It will make sense if you think about [Slope Intercept Form](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra-home/alg-linear-eq-func/alg-slope-intercept-form/v/slope-intercept-form) `y=mx+b` where `b` is the mid-line. So to break down your equation `f(x)=−6sin(3π+4)−2`

```
f(x) >>> y
 -6  >>> m
  x  >>> sin(3π+4)
 -2  >>> b
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the function $$f(x)=-6\sin(3\pi+4x)-2$$ in which the range goes from $-8$ till $4$ therefore the line $$y=-2$$ is such that cuts the graph of the function in points for which $\dfrac{-8+4}{2}=-2$ so your typo should be putting $4$ instead of $4x$.